# Which password need to generate hash key for Facebook API in Android?

Tags: android, hash, facebook-login

After went though [Getting Started FaceBook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), I get an error message after pressing in Android app the Login button:

**Invalid key hash. The key hash does not match ..**

None of the existing SO accepted answers were useful.

When generating the hash which password should I fill? Or an arbitrary password is ok?

I also tryed to fill in the hash key in error message into Facebook site, but it did not help.

I am using mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the keyhash generated by below code and put that keyhash into your facebook app,call this method in your Login Activity and get the keyhash from Logcat.

```
 try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "packagename",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

 }
```

Comment: Added logged hash key to FB portal, but now the confirmation screen does not appear, and can not go though login process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266772/pressing-facebook-login-button-does-nothing Do you have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

which OS you use?
In case you use windows:

1. go to your jdk/bin folder (usually in program files).
2. copy the path.
3. enter cmd.
4. enter: cd {here paste the path}.
5. search for your .android folder in your computer (usually in C:\Users\name)
6. copy the path.
7. now, enter this in cmd:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore {path from
>   6}.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

8. password: android
9. copy the code and use it in facebook web.

MAC:

in section 7:

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

don't forget to add in your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```